# Postgres how to turn a field into a json array

Tags: json, postgresql

I saved a json like this in a column of my db:

```
{"a":137,"b":"28","c":"1","d":"5","e":19,"f":true}
```

is it possible with a query to transform "e" into an array without removing the value?

```
{"a":137,"b":"28","c":"1","d":"5","e":[19],"f":true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update the_table
  set the_column = the_column||jsonb_build_object('e', array_to_json(array[the_column -> 'e']))
where ...
```

`array[the_column -> 'e']` creates a "native" array out of the single element referenced by the key `'e'`. This array is converted to JSON and a new JSON value is created using `jsonb_build_object()` which is then concatenated to the existing value. This will overwrite the existing key `"e"`.

The above assumes that the column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's only `json` you need to cast it to make the replacement work with `||`